# How to permanently remove content from a PDF based on coordinates on a page or pages

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, pdf

Given a PDF document that contains text, images, and all regular content objects, I would like to implement a secure Redaction feature.   That is, I'd like to draw a black rectangle on one or multiple coordinates on one or more pages in a document to block content from reading; but I would also like to permanently remove the content on the given coordinates.

For example, assume this document:

Page 1:
[image: Page 1 of PDF Document]
Page 2:
[image: Page 2 of PDF Document]

Then you draw a few black rectangles to block some content, effectively redacting the document in order to hide information you don't want visible.

Page 1 Redacted
[image: Page 1 Redacted]
Page 2 Redacted
[image: Page 2 Partial Image Redacted]

How can you achieve this in a secure way? My hypothesis is that you need to remove the content on the background and then draw the redaction rectangles.

The reason is that a user can use a PDF manipulation tool to remove the black rectangles and surface the content that we intended to hide.   For that, in addition to creating the black rectangles given some coordinates, I'd like to remove all objects from the coordinates before the drawing of the rectangles.     It can be text, or it can be images, or partial images.

One more thing:  I would prefer to do this with Node.js or with .NET as those are the technologies I am more familiar with.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It sounds like you need an API for removing or replacing objects in a PDF file.  Adobe has a tool for secure redacting, but I didn't see an API.  [This](https://www.activepdf.com/products/redactor) purports to be an API for it, but I can't tell if it's truly secure or not (actually removes the content from the PDF).

Comment: Here's a redaction API that looks like it works in nodejs: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/nodejs/guides/features/redaction/redact/.  FYI, search Google with "nodejs pdf redaction api".

Comment: @agarcian did you find any solution for this, I required same behavior for my nodejs project.

Comment: Check Datalogics.   It is a paid product but it will do exactly this